# Does a silkscreen text or line over pads/mounting holes give problems?

Tags: pcb, kicad, silkscreen

I'm intending to create a PCB and let it manufactured (just a few, for a hobby project).

I added some text on the silkscreen layer very close to mounting holes/holes for pins/vias.
Also I used lines over such holes.

Could this cause a problem for a PCB manufacturer? I expect the text/lines will just not be displayed, or will my PCB be rejected because of this?

I'm using KiCad for the design.

Below is the picture... meanwhile I fixed the texts, but the diagonal lines at the bottom through some pads and holes I would rather keep.

[image]

Comment: Won't you get a DRC err if you place text over pads ? - I imagine that over holes isn't a problem what so ever.

Comment: The PCB manufacturer will often remove parts of the silk screen that overlap holes and pads so you don't get a problem, but you're best checking and fixing that at the design stage.

Comment: @Sorenp You are probably right, I think it was just over holes of pin headers, not directly over pads (or at least not pads from SMD components); I will check when I have access to my project.

Comment: @SteveG Thanks ... Luckily KiCad has a 3D viewer, and I like the lines to go over the holes, to make the layout more clear (I can show a picture later if you want).

Comment: All the board houses I work with simply AND overlay layers with solder mask one.

Comment: @Sorenp I tried and I don't get a DRC error (meanwhile I fixed the texts, but I would like to keep the diagonal lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KiCad has no check for silkscreen overlapping exposed copper. But you can select "exclude pads from silkscreen" (formally known as "remove mask from silkscreen") during gerber export to ensure no silk is where it does not belong.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 1):

Usually they just mask/remove these problematic parts (at least at eurocircuits), but you should clear it with your PCB supplier or simply fix it.

Comment: Masking seems no problem, removing an entire line or text because it partly overlaps some hole, is not what I would like.

Comment: I don't think they do that, at least it never happened to me. They usually take some of the layers (usually solder mask), maybe increase the openings and substract it from the silkscreen.

Comment: I added a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Most full-service pcb fabricators will have a CAM department. These engineers normally clip off silkscreen which falls on holes or solderable surfaces. 
If they don't do that, you might encounter
1) Ink in holes, that might create issues while fitting a part/pin.
2) Ink on solderable surface, which might result in bad solder joints.

If it's just silkscreen outlines and unnecessary stuff, most CAM engineers clip them without putting the project on hold, but if it's text or polarity markings, they might put it on hold for verification.

For your board, just make sure which whoever is going to fabricate your board, if they would clip silkscreen with respect to soldermask/holes. If they do, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for that insight.  Since it's just some lines, I will change the lines in two (and do the clipping myself manually).